# Python flask WTForms custom validation - cant get data from form, is None

Tags: python, forms, validation

I have currently a problem with one of my form fields. The user has to choose or type in a valid category (which is predefined). To check whether the input is valid I created a custom validation:

```
class CategoryAddTextField(TextField):
    def process_formdata(self, valuelist):
        if len(valuelist[0].lower().strip()) > 0:
            if valuelist[0].lower().strip() not in cat_list:
                raise ValidationError("Diese Branche existiert nicht")
```

In `cat_list` I have all valid options (3300 ~) `cat_list` is a `list`.

Here is the inputfield:

```
category_add = CategoryAddTextField(u'Kategorie wählen')
```

If the input is wrong, everything works fine, the form does not submit and shows the correct error, but if the input is correct, then the form data is not stored. I tested it and it is `None`

If I use `print form.category_add.data` it tells me it is `None`

If I use the normal `TextField` it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay It seems there is a difference between:

```
form.category_add.data
```

The first version becomes `None`, while the second one becomes an `empty string`

```
request.form["category_add"]
```

Using the second version fixed my issue:

```
class CategoryAddTextField(TextField):
    def process_formdata(self, valuelist):
        if valuelist[0].lower().strip() == "":
            raise ValidationError("Suchen Sie eine Branche aus")
        if len(valuelist[0].lower().strip()) > 0:
            if valuelist[0].lower().strip() not in cat_list:
                raise ValidationError("Diese Branche existiert nicht")
```

I also added this to make sure that data was entered:

```
    if valuelist[0].lower().strip() == "":
        raise ValidationError("Suchen Sie eine Branche aus")
```

In the main.py adding to DB with `request.form["category_add"].lower().strip()`:

```
the_category =  CompanyCategory(category_info=form.category_info.data, category_id_name = request.form["category_add"].lower().strip(), company_id=the_company.id)
```